# Is an array.forEach with a splice the best way to remove an entry from an array of unique Ids?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. Each object has a unique userTestrId. Here is the code that I am using when I want to delete one of the objects. Is this the most efficient way I can perform the delete? What I am concerned with is once a row has been deleted the code will still go all the way through the array even though there is no chance of another entry:

```
var id = 99;
self.tests.forEach(function (elem, index) {
   if (elem['userTestId'] === id)
      self.tests.splice(index, 1);
   });
}
```

Comment: Think a for(...) with a possibility to 'break' on find would be more efficient (in most cases, unless the entry to be found was always the last)

Comment: You can't short-circuit `.forEach()` short of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var id = 99;
self.tests.some(function (elem, index) {
   if (elem['userTestId'] === id)
      self.tests.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
   });
   return false;
}
```

Could utilise [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)? Stops looping once you return TRUE from a callback.

Comment: Using `.every()` will also work and might be slightly more readable (need to return false to stop though).

Comment: This is really a misuse of `.some()` - code like this is hard to read because it doesn't do what you would expect it to do. :(

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to @benhowdle89's answer.

### Use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

The `.every` method is used to iterate over an array and check whether each and every element passes a test or not. If the callback returns false for any single element, the loop breaks.
Take the following example:

```js
var odds = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 17, 19];
//an array with all odd numbers except one
var checkEven = function (n, i, arr) {
  console.log ("Checking number ", n);
  if (n%2===0) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(odds.every(checkEven), odds);
```

If you run the above and look at the console, the loop executed till number 12 only, where it spliced, and stopped.

You can employ similar logic in your code very easily :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = 99;
self.tests.some(function (elem, index) {
   if (elem['userTestId'] === id)
      self.tests.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
   });
   return false;
}
```

**Polyfill :**
`some` was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as such it may not be present in all implementations of the standard. You can work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of your scripts, allowing use of some in implementations which do not natively support it.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.17
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.17
if (!Array.prototype.some) {
  Array.prototype.some = function(fun /*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
    }

    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```

[see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in detail

Answer (score 0):

While your concern is technically correct, it's unlikely to be an actual problem(Javascript is fast, this is a microoptimization).

What you should do is focus on using the appropriate interface, so your code could be easy to read and understand. `.forEach()` does not tell you what you want to *do*, unless you really do want to do something with each element of the array.

Lodash has the `.remove()` function, which removes all elements matching a predicate. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the exact specific function you wanted in JS's standard library or in lodash, so you would have to write your own wrapper:

```
var id = 99
removeFirst(tests, function (elem) { return elem.userTestId === id })

function removeFirst(array, callback) {
    var index = array.findIndex(callback)
    array.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Having noted that, you should avoid using an array at all - splicing is way more expensive than looping the whole array to begin with! Instead, since you have a unique identifier, you could use a map:

```
var map = {}
tests.forEach(function mapper(elem) {
    map[elem.userTestId] = elem
})
```

Now, your removal function is simply `delete map[id]`.